# YUI: Buttons in a datatable not rendered after a sort

Tags: javascript, yui, velocity

I'm developing a web page using YUI ( YAHOO User Interface Library ) and Velocity, and I have set a datatable with some buttons in one of the columns. My problem is that when I sort any of the columns, the buttons are not rendered anymore, ie that are display as simple input fields. Here part of the (simplified) code:

```
#set($states=['valid','invalid','empty'])

var buttonsFormatter = function(elLiner, oRecord, oColumn, oData) {
  elLiner.innerHTML = '';
  #foreach($state in $states)
    elLiner.innerHTML = elLiner.innerHTML+'<input id="${state}Button-'+oRecord.getData("id")+'"/>';
  #end
};

var myColumnDefs = [
  {key:"change",
   label: "Actions",
   formatter: buttonsFormatter,
   sortable: true,
   resizeable: true},
];

// Then create datasource, datatable, etc...

// $comment is the object I use to build the datasource
// So here I loop over records to instantiate the buttons
#foreach($comment in $comments_arraylist)
  new YAHOO.widget.Button("validButton-"+$comment.getId(),
      {label:'<img src="$content.getURI("images/gc.gif")"/>',
       title:'Valid',
       onclick:{ fn:makeRequest,obj:[$comment.getId(),"Valid"]}
      }
  ); 
  new YAHOO.widget.Button("invalidButton-"+$comment.getId(),
      {label:'<img src="$content.getURI("images/rc.gif")"/>',
       title:'Invalid',
       onclick:{ fn:makeRequest,obj:[$comment.getId(),"Invalid"]}
      }
  ); 
  new YAHOO.widget.Button("emptyButton-"+$comment.getId(),
      {label:'<img src="$content.getURI("images/close.jpg")"/>',
       title:'Reset',
       onclick:{ fn:makeRequest,obj:[$comment.getId(),"null"]}
      }
  ); 
#end
```

I have also tried to add the *new YAHOO.widget.Button...* declaration in the formatter function, but no more success. Does someone has an idea for me? I have to mention that except this issue on sorting, everything works fine.

Thanks

Alexis

---

Edit: Modification in the button formatter function this way doesn't help:

```
var buttonsFormatter = function(elLiner, oRecord, oColumn, oData) {
  elLiner.innerHTML = '';
  #foreach($state in $states)
    elLiner.innerHTML = elLiner.innerHTML+'<input type="button" id="${state}Button-'+oRecord.getData("id")+'"/>';
  #end
  elLiner.innerHTML = elLiner.innerHTML+'<input type="button" id="testButton-'+oRecord.getData("id")+'"/>';
  new YAHOO.widget.Button("testButton-"+oRecord.getData("id"),
      {label:'<img src="$content.getURI("images/gc.gif")"/>',
       title:'test',
       onclick:{ fn:makeRequest,obj:[oRecord.getData("id"),"test"]}
      }
  ); 
};
```

The so created 'test' button is never rendered, just appear as a basic empty button input.

Comment: Well, I couldn't sort this out I just disable the sortable property as it wasn't essential. Just for information: I also tried create button without pre-existing html, but could not succeed to insert it in the formatter function: trying to do "...innerHtml = myButton.toString()" displays something like "button-id254..."

Answer (score 0):

Your "buttonsFormatter" function is creating text input elements.  I think you need to have a 'type="button"' attribute on the  element you are creating there.

I *think* I understand why you are calling new YAHOO.widget.Button, but you should do that in the formatter function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it didn't really fixed the problem: adding the 'type="button"' made it rendered as a button rather than a text input, but didn't do anything regarding the YAHOO.widget.Button declaration, so basically there's no icon and the link doesn't work. I will edit my question to illustrate this.